# Simple counter with boolean in python

Tags: python

```py
counter = True
while counter < 20:
    counter = counter+1
print(counter)
```

I am trying to print numbers from 1 to 21 with using the boolean method, as i mentioned above the output always two because python counts True as 1 adds 1 = 2.

Comment: It's very strange to add `1` to `True`.  If you want it to be an integer, use `1` instead of `True` (or perhaps you want `0`).  That way it will be much clearer.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Your question isn;t clear; What is "the boolean method"? Is that why you are initializing a counter with a boolean instead of a number?

Comment: Thanks for your response @G.Anderson My question is basically i have to make a counter starts from 1 to 21 with using boolean.
 'counter = 1
while counter < 20: 
   print(counter) 
   counter = counter+1'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is scoping. You should place the `print` function within the loop, as shown below. As it stands, the `print` function is only invoked once when the looping is over.

```py
counter = True
while counter < 22:
    print(counter)
    counter = counter+1
```

Also, you need to pay close attention to the condition of the `while` loop. Because `counter` starts from 1, you want to first print the value of counter. Then, as we increment counter, we want to stop when `counter < 22` for us to be able to print values from 1 to 21. Think this through and you will be able to derive the correct exit condition.

I'd be happy to answer any additional questions you might have.

Comment: My point is this snipper starts from true to 21

Comment: @MohammedAmwar A Boolean variable that takes the value of `True` is equal to 1. Try something like `x = True`, then `print(x + 1)`. You should see 2 as the result. So by saying that counter starts from `True` to 21, it's equal to saying that it ranges from 1 to 21.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pay attention to indentation here.

```
counter = True
while counter < 20:
    counter = counter+1
print(counter) # will only be run once because it isn't indented under the loop
```

Furthermore, you can set counter to be equal to something more reasonable and adjust the bounds so that 21 is included:

```
counter = 0
while counter <= 20:
    counter = counter+1
    print(counter)
```

Comment: This is the current issue right now its printing true as well. sadly i have to use the boolean method for this. But i couldnt find any answers for this.
There is little hint : it says four lines of codes one to assign a variable one to start the while loop one to use in place addition operator to add something to a variable and one to print variable @Ryan Schaefer